# How come my image wont change when key is pressed?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

So what I am trying to do here is to make my character change the image when I press it, but when I do I get an error? Link to full code is below **

https://pastebin.com/NDqjMvJK

```py
      def draw(self, win):
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 10:
                self.walkCount = 0
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
                win.blit("image/goku-ki.png", (self.x, self.y))
            if not (self.standing):
                if self.left:
                    win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                    self.walkCount += 1
                elif self.right:
                    win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                    self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                if self.right:
                    win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
                else:
                    win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
```

Here is what the Error looks like when I press 'a', please help

```py
    "C:\Users\Rafael Perez\AppData\Local\Temp\pygame1.py\venv\Python37\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Rafael Perez/PycharmProjects/game_two/game_compeleted.py"
    pygame 1.9.6
    Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Rafael Perez/PycharmProjects/game_two/game_compeleted.py", line 365, in <module>
        redrawGameWindow()
      File "C:/Users/Rafael Perez/PycharmProjects/game_two/game_compeleted.py", line 245, in redrawGameWindow
        man.draw(win)
      File "C:/Users/Rafael Perez/PycharmProjects/game_two/game_compeleted.py", line 46, in draw
        win.blit("image/goku-ki.png", (self.x, self.y))
    TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bliting the image path, not the image, change

```
win.blit("image/goku-ki.png", (self.x, self.y))
```

to

```
win.blit(ki_stance, (self.x, self.y))
```